# Alias for PsIsContainer?

Tags: powershell

Instead of typing PsIsContainer, I would like to be able to use either "dir" or "folder" strings.  Is there a way in PowerShell that allows me to substitute one string for another, as in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *think* you could get close to what you're afer by predefining a couple of scriptblocks e.g.:

```
$IsDir = {$_.PsIsContainer}
$IsFile = {!$_.PsIsContainer}
dir | Where $IsDir
dir | Where $IsFile
```

Good news in PowerShell V3.  This is supported natively e.g.:

```
dir -directory
dir -ad
dir -file
dir -af
```

Comment: i like the *nix functions like dird: function dird { dir | ? { $_.psiscontainer} }

Answer (score 5):

You could update your TypeData for the `System.IO.FileInfo` type using the following file and the `Update-TypeData` cmdlet.

*D:\fileinfo.ps1xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Types>
    <Type>
        <Name>System.IO.FileSystemInfo</Name>
        <Members>
            <ScriptProperty>
                <Name>dir</Name>
                <GetScriptBlock>
                 $this.psiscontainer
                </GetScriptBlock>
            </ScriptProperty>
        <ScriptProperty>
                <Name>file</Name>
                <GetScriptBlock>
                 ! ($this.psiscontainer)
                </GetScriptBlock>
            </ScriptProperty>
        </Members>
     </Type>
</Types>
```

Update the TypeData:

```
update-typedata D:\fileinfo.ps1xml
```

Now you will be able to type:

```
gci | ?{$_.dir}
```

and

```
gci | ?{$_.file}
```

Comment: +1 for introducing an entirely new area to research.  Thanks.